# Recover review list from Google My Business API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-my-business-api, insomnia, google-reviews

I'm trying to recover list of review from google to displayed them on a customer's website.
I discovered this [API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews) and i thought I could use it but I'm having some issue doing so.

Customer asked access to this API and then gave me oauth2 credentials.

Before calling this API from code I wanted to try it from Insomnia, I used OAuth2 method as specified in doc, there are my parameters :

[image: Insomnia parameters]

Without redirect url I have is error :
[image: error]

But with I have a popup to login to google account, I don't understand why as I have provided client id and secret, shouldn't be enough for authentification ?

I don't know if I'm missing something or have configuration issue somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Client id and secret relate to your general access to the GMB API and the GCP project.

The pop-up authentication is for GBP API data access scope - so you need to use a Google account that actually owns GBP locations that have the reviews you want to retrieve.